# Laravel run event inside job queue async

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 9, I have simple Job which processes a large number of images on the server

```
class ExchangeJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
       
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $ImageObject = new \App\Core\Images;
        $ImageObject->ProductsImagesRegenerate();
    }
}
```

Internally, I call a queue to inform the user about the progress of the process.
I use a pusher and a subscription to notifications

```
 public function ProductsImagesRegenerate(): void {
 

     NoticeEvent::dispatch('Starting processing notice');

     $images = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
     
     foreach ($images as $value) {

           NoticeEvent::dispatch($value);
     }


     event(new NoticeEvent("End processing images"));

 }
```

Problem is that the  event is called synchronously.  Job starts first, it runs in the background. During the execution of the Job, all events are placed in some kind of queue and they are not called until the job is done, then they fire. I need Job in the background and receive notifications from the pusher during its execution.

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Now Job is done first, and only after it is completed, event notifications begin to be executed.  How to receive event pusher notifications asynchronously while doing job in the background?

```
  2022-12-10 20:45:41 App\Jobs\ExchangeJob ........................... RUNNING
  2022-12-10 20:45:55 App\Jobs\ExchangeJob .................. 13,073.61ms DONE
  2022-12-10 20:45:55 App\Events\NoticeEvent ......................... RUNNING
  2022-12-10 20:45:55 App\Events\NoticeEvent ................... 333.14ms DONE
  2022-12-10 20:45:56 App\Events\NoticeEvent ......................... RUNNING
  2022-12-10 20:45:56 App\Events\NoticeEvent ................... 265.29ms DONE
  2022-12-10 20:45:57 App\Events\NoticeEvent ......................... RUNNING
  2022-12-10 20:45:57 App\Events\NoticeEvent ................... 294.35ms DONE
  2022-12-10 20:45:58 App\Events\NoticeEvent ......................... RUNNING
  2022-12-10 20:45:58 App\Events\NoticeEvent ................... 298.30ms DONE
  2022-12-10 20:45:58 App\Events\NoticeEvent ......................... RUNNING
  2022-12-10 20:45:59 App\Events\NoticeEvent ................... 276.32ms DONE
  2022-12-10 20:45:59 App\Events\NoticeEvent ......................... RUNNING
  2022-12-10 20:46:00 App\Events\NoticeEvent ................... 278.33ms DONE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your NoticeEvent is queued on the same queue as you ExchangeJob. Since there is only one worker process (php artisan queue:listen) running they can't be executed in parallel.

Try to start at least two worker processes (run `php artisan queue:listen`  in an additional terminal). In addition you should use separate queues and workers for ExchangeJob and NoticeEvent to make sure the NoticeEvents are not blocked by other long running ExchangeJobs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with the detailed explanation. If I understand correctly, then I need to create another connection  for new queue, for example on redis. And send push messages from this queue. And in order to start this queue, I will need to start another worker process in the terminal? You need two separate queues (database drivers and redis driver), and run two worker processes in the terminals to listen to them in parallel

Comment: welcome. No need for another connection (driver), please check: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#connections-vs-queues